# Highlight marker when click and remove previous highlight in Leaflet

Tags: leaflet, select, markers

This is a follow up question to "[Error changing marker icon when clicked in Leaflet](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/459425/error-changing-marker-icon-when-clicked-in-leaflet)".
I want to highlight a marker when clicked but at the same time reset previously highlighted marker. I used the code below but there are some flaws in the logic which I could not correct it.

```
        var selectedLayer;
                
        function highlightSchool(e) {
            removeHighlight;
            var layer = e.target;
            layer.setIcon(highlightIcon);
            selectedLayer = layer;
        }
        
        function removeHighlight(e) {
            layer = e.target;
            if(selectedLayer!== layer){
                selectedLayer.setIcon(primaryIcon); 
            }
                    
        }
            
        function onEachFeatureSchool(feature, layer) {
            layer.on({
                //mouseout: removeHighlight,
                click: highlightSchool
            });
        }

var schoolP = new L.GeoJSON.AJAX('data/schools.json', {pointToLayer:function(feature,latlng){
            var str= "<h6><b>"+feature.properties.sch_name+", "+feature.properties.sch_loc+"</b><br>Primary Schools</h6>";
                    return L.marker(latlng,{icon: primaryIcon}).bindPopup(str);                             
        }onEachFeature: onEachFeatureSchool});
         
        schoolP.addTo(mymap);
```

Comment: does https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54651/change-marker-icon-on-click-using-leaflet answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First reason why your code does not work as expected is the way you try to call function `removeHighlight`. To execute it, it should be at least `removeHighlight()`, but it would not work without parameter. So it should be `removeHighlight(e)`.

Event if you correct this, `removeHighlight` would fail, since first time `selectedLayer` is undefined, so `selectedLayer.setIcon(primaryIcon)` would fail.

So relevant part of the code could then look something like this:

```
function highlightSchool(e) {
  var layer = e.target;
  removeHighlight(layer);
  layer.setIcon(highlightIcon);
  selectedLayer = layer;
}

function removeHighlight(layer) {
  if (selectedLayer && (selectedLayer !== layer)){
    selectedLayer.setIcon(primaryIcon); 
  }       
}
```

Comment: Thanks @TomazicM. Yes, this works perfectly fine. I have implemented bit differently though. I used your previous answer (in another thread) in combination with the solution described in [https://plnkr.co/edit/aqiImS?p=preview&preview]. Anyway, it works now the way I wanted, so thank you so much.